# regex - matching number with optional range

Tags: python, regex

Using python's re module, I'm trying to get the dollar values from statements such as:

- "$305,000 - $349,950" should give a tuple like this (305000, 349950)
- "Mid $2M's Buyers" --> (2000000)
- "... Buyers Guide $1.29M+" --> (1290000)
- "...$485,000 and $510,000" --> (485000, 510000)

The pattern below works for single values but if there are ranges (like in the first and last dot point above) it only gives me the last number (i.e. 349950 and 510000).

```
_pattern = r"""(?x)
    ^
    .*
    (?P<target1>
        [€$£]
        \d{1,3}
        [,.]?
        \d{0,3}
        (?:[,.]\d{3})*
        (?P<multiplyer1>[kKmM]?\s?[mM]?)
    )
    (?:\s(?:\-|\band\b|\bto\b)\s)?
    (?P<target2>
        [€$£]
        \d{1,3}
        [,.]?
        \d{0,3}
        (?:[,.]\d{3})*
        (?P<multiplyer2>[kKmM]?\s?[mM]?)
    )?
    .*?
    $
    """
```

When trying `target2 = match.group("target2").strip()` target2 always appears to be `None`.

I'm by no means a regexpert but can't really see what I'm doing wrong here. The multiplyer group works and to me it seems that the target2 group is the same pattern, i.e. and optional match at the end.

I hope I'm phrasing this somewhat understandably...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 for using verbose mode for the regex pattern

The `.*` at the beginning of the pattern is greedy, so it tries to match the entire line.  Then it backtracks to match target1.  Everything else in the pattern is optional, so matching target1 to the last match on the line is a successful match. You can try making the first `.*` not greedy by adding a '?' like so:

```
_pattern = r"""(?x)
    ^
    .*?                   <-- add the ?
    (?P<target1>
    ... snip ...
    """
```

Can you do it incrementally?

```
_pattern = r"""(?x)
    (?P<target1>
        [€$£]
        \d{1,3}
        [,.]?
        \d{0,3}
        (?:[,.]\d{3})*
        (?P<multiplyer1>[kKmM]?\s?[mM]?)
    )
    (?P<more>\s(?:\-|\band\b|\bto\b)\s)?
    """

match = re.search(_pattern, line)
target1, more = match.groups()
if more:
    target2 = re.search(_pattern, line, start=match.end())
```

**Edit**
One more thought: try re.findall():

```
_pattern = r"""(?x)
    (?P<target1>
        [€$£]
        \d{1,3}
        [,.]?
        \d{0,3}
        (?:[,.]\d{3})*
        (?P<multiplyer1>[kKmM]?\s?[mM]?)
    )
"""

targets = re.findall(_pattern, line)
```

Comment: The first option didn't work unfortunately. The result was the same though it reported the first number in the ranges. I thought you second suggestion was a good idea however it didn't work either. Btw the syntax seems to be `re.search(patter, line)`. Anyway the `more` group also always seems to be none....

Comment: Fixed the call to re.search()

Comment: Can you use re.findall()? with just the pattern for target1?  It should return a list of all the matches.

Comment: Yep, I can get that to work :) without the `<more>` group it returns e.g. `([('$305,000 ', ' '), ('$349,950', '')], 349950)` for a range! I think that there were some issues with the regex in the `more` group but anyway using re.findall() works well. If you add something around this to your answer I'll mark it accepted. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You could come up with some regex logic combined with a function converting the abbreviated numbers. Here's some example python code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8> -*-
import re, locale
from locale import *
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8') 

string = """"$305,000 - $349,950"
"Mid $2M's Buyers"
"... Buyers Guide $1.29M+"
"...$485,000 and $510,000"
"""

def convert_number(number, unit):
    if unit == "K":
        exp = 10**3
    elif unit == "M":
        exp = 10**6
    return (atof(number) * exp)

matches = []
rx = r"""
    \$(?P<value>\d+[\d,.]*)         # match a dollar sign 
                                    # followed by numbers, dots and commas
                                    # make the first digit necessary (+)
    (?P<unit>M|K)?                  # match M or K and save it to a group
    (                               # opening parenthesis
        \s(?:-|and)\s               # match a whitespace, dash or "and"
        \$(?P<value1>\d+[\d,.]*)    # the same pattern as above
        (?P<unit1>M|K)?
    )?                              # closing parethesis, 
                                    # make the whole subpattern optional (?)
"""
for match in re.finditer(rx, string, re.VERBOSE):
    if match.group('unit') is not None:
        value1 = convert_number(match.group('value'), match.group('unit'))
    else:
        value1 = atof(match.group('value'))
    m = (value1)
    if match.group('value1') is not None:
        if match.group('unit1') is not None:
            value2 = convert_number(match.group('value1'), match.group('unit1'))
        else:
            value2 = atof(match.group('value1'))
        m = (value1, value2)
    matches.append(m)

print matches
# [(305000.0, 349950.0), 2000000.0, 1290000.0, (485000.0, 510000.0)]
```

The code uses quite some logic, it first imports the `locale` module for the `atof()` function, defines a function `convert_number()` and searches for ranges with a regular expression which is explained in the code. You could obviously add other currency symbols like `€$£` but they weren't in your original examples.

Comment: I like this solution. While this is not a pure regex solution it is easier to understand

Comment: @murphy: It does not have to be regex alone, in my opinion :)

Comment: yep. If I have to debug this code, say in 3 months, I have good chance to understand it at once. If I use a wicked regex it's good for my ego now, but makes me hate myself in 3 months :)

Comment: +1 Thanks Jan, I'm actually doing something similar already to convert the abbreviations. My issue with the pattern in the question was more that for some reason it didn't pick up the second target when there was a range given as input. I.e. "$340,000 - $400,000" missed the lower bound and only matched $400,000.

Comment: I know and I would have marked yours as the correct answer. It was just that @RootTwo came up with a pattern that worked for me just before your post.

Comment: @pandita: No worries about the accepted or not accepted answer (I'm not greedy ;-), just to make sure the code works.